# Receiving a not expected date after formating with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, formatting, momentjs

I'm having problems formatting a date. I expect to receive the date "12/07/2016" instead of "13/07/2016". Why a day is added to my formatted date?

```
$("#donationDate").val("2016-07-12 00:00:00.0");            
$("#donationDate").val(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
console.log($("#donationDate").val());
```

Best wishes,

Ivan

Comment: You are not specifying a time zone, so probably that's why. One date will be in one time zone and server in another and boom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#donationDate").val(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'));`

You haven't pass anything in params to `moment()`.Therefore by default it returns a moment object corresponding the current moment ( today we are the 13th of July ).

Then you are plugging a `.format()` that formats the moment object to `DD-MM-YYYY`. That's why it returns `13-07-2016`.

You probably wanted to do something like `moment(2016-07-12 00:00:00.0).format('DD-MM-YYYY')` which returns `12-07-2016`